# Data Replication Approaches for Hot Standby Architecture

Tags: filesystems, storage, drbd, glusterfs, high-availability

I'm relatively new to the world of storage & filesystems (please forgive me if I'm not using the correct language), and I'm currently researching ways to achieve a hot standby configuration -- i.e. a setup whereby files are concurrently available from two different machines at the same time, so that a standby host can take over in case of a failover (this question is about data replication, *not* the orchestration of failover). But, I'm getting a little confused about the pros / cons of different approaches.

From the research that I have done so far, it seems like there are two different approaches that could be taken:

- DRBD + some shared disk file system (DRBD 9 supports dual-primary configurations)
- A distributed filesystem that is also capable of replication (e.g. GlusterFS, Ceph, &c.)

I think that I understand the conceptual differences between the two approaches:

DRBD is operating at the block level (which as I understand it is the lowest level at which you can deal, since the blocks of a file are what get physically written to disk), and that's what's being replicated across machines. The additional filesystem is necessary because a synchronous filesystem (not sure if that's the right term to be using) like `ext3` is unaware that the blocks it's working on can change because of something that's happening on a different machine. Therefore, there can be a mismatch between what the filesystem *thinks* is on disk, and what's actually there, leading to data corruption.

GlusterFS (or something similar), however, operates on the file level, and doesn't give you access to the actual blocks that are being written out to disk. It instead operates on whole files at a time, and you as a user don't have to worry or interact with what physically gets written to disk. The conceptual model that I have in my head is that it's a distributed filesystem -- i.e. that files (either in their entirety or individual pieces of them) in a filesystem can be stored across multiple machines, but appear to the user as a unified entity -- that also has replication capabilities.

So my question is:

1. Am I correct in my conceptual understanding of these two different approaches ?
2. Beyond the conceptual differences, what are the actual pros / cons of one approach vs the other? Why would you want to work on the block level instead of the file level and vice versa ?